# Want to transform JSON data

Tags: javascript

I have below object

```
var obj_old = {'team':'arsenal', 'league':'premier','position': '3'}
var obj_new = {'team':'arsenal_1', 'league':'premier_1','position': '32'}

Want output [
          { 'key' : 'team', 'old' : 'arsenal', 'new' : 'arsenal_1' },
          { 'key' : 'league', 'old' : 'premier', 'new' : 'premier_1' },
          { 'key' : 'position', 'old' : '3', 'new' : '32' }
        ]
===================================================================================================
var obj_old = {'team':'arsenal', 'league':'premier','position': '3'}
var obj_new = {'team':'arsenal_1', 'league':'premier_1','position': '32'}
var count = Object.keys(obj_old).length; 
const out = []
for(x in Object.keys(obj_old)){
    for(y in Object.keys(obj_new)){
        if(obj_old[x] == obj_new[y]){
            alert("rohan");
        }
     
    }
}
```

Is I am going right direction or any other logic will be appreciated which is simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You need only one loop

```js
const obj_old = {
  'team': 'arsenal',
  'league': 'premier',
  'position': '3'
}
const obj_new = {
  'team': 'arsenal_1',
  'league': 'premier_1',
  'position': '32'
}

const output = Object.keys(obj_old).map(key => ({
  key,
  old: obj_old[key],
  new: obj_new[key]
}))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just map the `Object.entries` for the new object and refer back to the `obj_old` for the original value.

```js
const
  obj_old = { team: 'arsenal'   , league: 'premier'   , position: '3'  },
  obj_new = { team: 'arsenal_1' , league: 'premier_1' , position: '32' };

const diff = Object.entries(obj_new).map(([key, newValue]) =>
  ({ key, old: obj_old[key], new: newValue }));

console.log(diff);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```